# PHP proc_open() with timeout

Tags: php, linux, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, shell-exec, proc-open

I want to call `proc_open` to execute a script in the background, and the background process will terminate after a few seconds. Basically, the script is a C/Java/Python script that will compile and run the user submitted code, so I want the process to be able to be terminated after some time.

What I want to achieve is that when the execution time of the background running script exceeds, say 3 seconds, halt the process as well as stop writing to the file. Let's say I run a for loop to write `1 million lines` of some string to a file, and at `time >= 3 seconds`, the process stops. When I retrieve back the file, I will get like `200k lines` of string. Then I can display the output of the file back to the browser.

I am currently using the function `exec_timeout` from https://blog.dubbelboer.com/2012/08/24/execute-with-timeout.html.
Then I execute a command `exec_timeout("exec nohup java -cp some_dir compiled_java_file &", 3)`, the background process will not be terminated even if it already exceeds the timeout value, instead it will continue to write to the file until it completes. Then only I can echo the result back to the browser. If the user submits a infinite running code, the process would just hanging there until I kill it in ec2 linux instance.

Any idea of why it is not functioning as expected? Or any better function available to achieve my goal? My application is developed in PHP and hosted on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

Answer (score 0):

On [proc_terminate manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.proc-terminate.php), first user contributed notes:

> As explained in http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39992, proc_terminate()
>   leaves children of the child process running. In my application, these
>   children often have infinite loops, so I need a sure way to kill
>   processes created with proc_open(). When I call proc_terminate(), the
>   /bin/sh process is killed, but the child with the infinite loop is
>   left running.

On exec_timeout:

```
proc_terminate($process, 9);
```

should be replaced by:

```
$status = proc_get_status($process);
if($status['running'] == true) { //process ran too long, kill it

    //get the parent pid of the process we want to kill
    $ppid = $status['pid'];
    //use ps to get all the children of this process, and kill them
    $pids = preg_split('/\s+/', `ps -o pid --no-heading --ppid $ppid`);
    foreach($pids as $pid) {
        if(is_numeric($pid)) {
            echo "Killing $pid\n";
            posix_kill($pid, 9); //9 is the SIGKILL signal
        }
    }
    proc_close($process);
}
```

Comment: I did actually try this and it does not work. I think my problem is more like the main script has to wait for the 'background' process to finish and then only it returns the result back to the browser.

Comment: preg_split('/\s+/', `ps -o pid --no-heading --ppid $ppid`); has no sense